# Missing signal in VCD output of GHDL

Tags: vhdl, ghdl, vcd

I am attempting a simple case question in a VHDL book. As you can understand from the source code, it sets the output value depending on input range. However, I couldn't observe my input, `x`, when I run the testbench using GHDL.

Is this because `x` is a `character` type? Should I ask on GHDL issues page (https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues)?

Source code (q4_case.vhd):

```
entity q4_case is

  port (
    x               : in  character;    -- input
    character_class : out integer);     -- output

end entity q4_case;

architecture behav of q4_case is

begin  -- architecture behav

  -- purpose: set output depending on range of input
  -- type   : combinational
  -- inputs : x
  -- outputs: character_class
  process (x) is
  begin  -- process
    case x is
      when 'A' to 'z'       => character_class <= 1;
      when '0' to '9'       => character_class <= 2;
      when nul to usp | del => character_class <= 4;
      when others           => character_class <= 3;
    end case;
  end process;


end architecture behav;
```

Test bench (q4_case_tb.vhd):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

entity q4_case_tb is

end entity q4_case_tb;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

architecture q4_case_tb of q4_case_tb is

  -- component ports
  signal x               : character;
  signal character_class : integer;

  -- clock
  signal Clk : std_logic := '1';

begin  -- architecture q4_case_tb

  -- component instantiation
  DUT : entity work.q4_case
    port map (
      x               => x,
      character_class => character_class);

  -- clock generation
  Clk <= not Clk after 10 ns;

  -- waveform generation
  WaveGen_Proc : process
  begin
    -- insert signal assignments here

    x <= 'b';
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';

    x <= 'F';
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';

    x <= dc3;
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';

    x <= usp;
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';

    x <= del;
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';

    x <= '0';
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';

    x <= '5';
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';

    x <= '9';
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';

    x <= '=';
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';

    x <= 'Ü';
    wait until Clk = '1';
    wait until Clk = '0';


    report "End of simulation" severity failure;

  end process WaveGen_Proc;



end architecture q4_case_tb;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

configuration q4_case_tb_q4_case_tb_cfg of q4_case_tb is
  for q4_case_tb
  end for;
end q4_case_tb_q4_case_tb_cfg;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Compile and run commands:

```
ghdl -a q4_case.vhd

ghdl -a q4_case_tb.vhd

ghdl -r q4_case_tb --vcd=q4_case.vcd
```

Version information:

```
ghdl -v
GHDL 0.35 (tarball) [Dunoon edition]
 Compiled with GNAT Version: GPL 2017 (20170515-63)
 mcode code generator
Written by Tristan Gingold.

Copyright (C) 2003 - 2015 Tristan Gingold.
GHDL is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Beginning of VCD output file is given below. As you can see, `x` is not handled and I can't observe `x` by viewing with GTKWave.

Part of VCD:

```
$date
  Thu Feb 08 09:19:40 2018
$end
$version
  GHDL v0
$end
$timescale
  1 fs
$end
$comment x is not handled $end
$var integer 32 ! character_class $end
$var reg 1 " clk $end
$scope module dut $end
$comment x is not handled $end
$var integer 32 # character_class $end
$upscope $end
$enddefinitions $end
#0
b1 !
1"
b1 #
#10000000
...
...
```

Comment: It would appear both DC3 and DEL you are using as stimulus demonstrate a gtkwave bug, either of those values cause gtkwave to crash dump file types fst and ghw. It would appear gtkwave is using in band signalling for storing value strings for x. As a work around you can add `signal char_pos: integer range 0 to 255;` and an assignment `char_pos <= character'pos(x);` to display in gtkwave as decimal or ascii (noting non-graphic characters are shown with '.'). If you don't add x to the gtkwave waveform it won't crash.

Comment: Does VCD support characters? If not, (a) use GHW which does, or convert from character to something (integer?) that VCD does support.

Comment: @user1155120 I think, the problem isn't related to gtkwave because signal information is missing in VCD file. Also, gtkwave didn't crash in my case. I understand work around approach, thank you.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, you are right. I missed the list of types supported by VCD file. It is listed there: http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/Simulation.html and character isn't supported by VCD. I switched to GHW and was able to observe signal in gtkwave. I am editing my question now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is not with GHDL per se, but with the fact that it uses the [Verilog VCD format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_change_dump) for recording waveforms. That Wikipedia page says

> The standard, four-value VCD format was defined along with the Verilog hardware description language by the IEEE Standard 1364-1995 in 1996.

Those four-values are 0, 1, X and Z.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In addition, it is able to record std_ulogic. I could record a std_ulogic signal using VCD. It is stated in as Extended VCD in Wikipeadia page, I think. I found that possible types allowed in VCD format is written there: http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/Simulation.html. Character isn't supported and I recorded the signal with character type using GHW format. Editing my question now..

Comment: Oh wait! character is in `std.standard`, right? It should be supported by GHDL and VCD according to  http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/Simulation.html  Hmm...

Comment: My reading of ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/Simulation.html is that **only** these types (**which happen to be in std.standard**) are supported: bit and 
bit_vector

Comment: I'll fix the wrong indentation in the documentation files.

Comment: @Paebbels I see your fix, this looks better now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's my fault that I didn't check the GHDL documentation properly. As written at https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/Simulation.html (and Matthew pointed out), only `bit` and `bit_vector` from `std.standard` are supported by VCD format. It is not possible to observe a `character` type signal with a VCD file.

As Brain suggested switching from VCD to GHW format solved the problem. For this case, GKTWave displayed the GHW file without any problem.

Comment: The VCD (value change dump) format is part of the Verilog standard. Thus, only Verilog types are supported.